# PHP Timestamp timer with reset

Tags: php

**Hi Stackers,**

I'm having a PHP Question (again). This time it's about time. I've created a timer, which gets the latest time from a database field, and when the new date is received, will insert a new row with a new time, so that the game can reset. However, when I test it, it doesn't seem to work. There is no error, but the date becomes the first one you can have in a Timestamp.

What am I doing wrong?

**magicaltimer.php**

```
    // Get Time Information.
    $get_timeinformation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magical_gametimer WHERE game = 'ctv' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $timeinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_timeinformation);
    $basetime = $timeinfo['time'];

    // Get the new Time.
    $newtime = strtotime('+21 days', $basetime);
    $testtime = "1471738828";

    // Get the reset date information.
    $date = date('d/m/Y', $newtime);
    $today = date('d/m/Y');
    $today_timestamped = date("d/m/Y",time());
    $new_resettime = strtotime('+21 days', $today_timestamped);

        // Check if, and when, reset the game!
        if ($date == $today) {
          $error = "<div class='geenTeamlid' style='margin-bottom: 5px;'>Olla! Je komt <strong>precies</strong> tijdens een reset binnen. We gaan je pagina herladen!.</div>";
          $insert_time = mysql_query("INSERT INTO magical_gametimer (timetitle, time, game) VALUES ('Round Timer: CTV', '".$new_resettime."', 'ctv')");
        }

    // Make the time visible, for the cracker to be seen.
    $resetdate = date('d/m/Y', $newtime);
```

Comment: What is the database `time` column datatype? And actually some output of the variables might help debugging the code. Because a timestamp and datetime are 2 different things.

Comment: @Xorifelse It's just a varchar, maybe not that good. The `$resetdate` variable will output the date. That works, however, when adding a row in the database by date, the new `$resetdate` will be showing `21/01/1970` It should output `10/9/2016` or `11/9/2016`. I'm not 100% sure. It should count 21 days at the old date.

Comment: Show me some actual results in the variables with a comment behind the variable. I haven't been using these functions since PHP 4, you should concider hopping over to the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and use the actual datetime db datatypes as you can run datetime manipulation functions on them. I have a feeling the time stored in the db is an integer, a timestamp and that the solution would be `$new_resettime = strtotime('+21 days');` cause `$today_timestamped` is not a timestamp and would output the beginning of the epoch.